# Convert Object to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have to convert a generic object(s) into a NameValueCollection.  I am attempting to use reflection. While I can get the parent properties, I cannot get the properties of a parent property that is an object.

```
Class One 
public string name{get;set}

Class Two
public string desc{get;set}
public One OneName{get;set;}

public static NameValueCollection GetPropertyName(
        string objType, object objectItem)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(objType);
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();
    NameValueCollection propNames = new NameValueCollection();

    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in objectItem.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
        {
            var pName = propertyInfo.Name;
            var pValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectItem, null);
            if (pValue != null)
            {
                propNames.Add(pName, pValue.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    return propNames;
}
```

I assume there has to be somesort of recursive call but cannot figure out how to do it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `objType` the type of `objectItem`? If so you can remove that parameter. You have also created a `propertyInfos` variable that you do not use.

Comment: I could use this code right about now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you want resulting `NameValueCollection` to contain properties from both `Class One` and `Class Two` when the input is of type `Class Two`.

Now that we have that established, what you can do is to examine a type of each property. 
If it's one of built-in types ([`Type.IsPrimitive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) can help you determine that), you can add the property to resulting `NameValueCollection` right away. Otherwise, you need to go over each property of that non-primitive type and repeat the process for it again. As you mention, here is the place for recursion.